# Serial Reading with Python

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I have a rectifier outputting voltage and amperage information every 3 seconds. I installed python 2.7 and pySerial without a hitch. I am trying to get the following code to read data being sent at baud 2400, 7 data bits, even parity, and one stop bit. Other RS232 programs get it without a hitch. When I start the program from cmd I get a blinking underscore. What am I doing wrong?

```
import time
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
    port='COM3',
    baudrate=2400,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS
)

while True:
    message = ser.readline()
    print(message)
    time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: is your sensor sending a \n ?

Comment: Hmm, didn't you say "even parity", but you are using `serial.PARITY_NONE` in your python code? Shouldn't that be `serial.PARITY_EVEN`?

Comment: Sensory is not sending an "\n". Does it need to?

Comment: I changed the parity to PARITY_EVEN. Still to response.

Comment: if your doing `readline` yeah ... try changing it to `read` (does it send any kind of signal that says OK done sending? or it just stops sending?)

Comment: I recall having some strange problems with ``ser.readline()`` under Windows. My workaround is to  always read character for character with ``ser.read(1)``and check for ``\n`` (or ``ser.read(100)`` and wait for timeout). As a far as I remember, the problem was Windows specific (not Linux), but I never took the time to look more deeply for reasons.